# MER - Modelo entidade e relacionamento

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle, modelagem

Gostaria de saber se meu MER está correto e se é possível faze um relacionamento N:N entre animais e agendamentos.

Especificações que eu criei para o sistema:

Informatizar os agendamentos de um banho e tosa, envolvendo os clientes, atendentes, animais, solicitação de agendamentos, agendamentos, serviços.

- O sistema permitirá o cliente se cadastrar no sistema;
- O sistema permitirá o cliente cadastrar seus animais no sistema;
- O sistema permitirá o cliente escolher qual atendente ele irá fazer o serviço;
- O sistema permitirá o cliente fazer solicitações de agendamentos;
- O sistema permitirá o atendente aprovar ou cancelar as solicitações;
- O sistema permitirá o atendente cadastrar novos serviços;
- O sistema permitirá o cliente fazer a solicitação de agendamento com busca do animal em casa;
- O sistema permitirá parametrizar o horario de disponibilidade do atendente;
- O sistema permitirá parametrizar o horario de disponiblidade do banho e tosa;

[image: MER]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso depende muito do fluxo de informações/regras de negócio de sua aplicação. Por exemplo, caso necessário mais de um endereço, poderia haver a tabela endereço e cliente separadas. No geral (com exceções), toda informação que se repete deve haver uma tabela específica e ser "laçada" com um ID referente.

Para um relacionamento N:N para animais e agendamentos, talvez a inclusão de uma tabela com as colunas ID - ID_ANIMAL - ID_AGENDAMENTO resolveria seu problema.

Recomento haver um histórico de serviços para os animais e a possibilidade de cadastro de mais de um serviço para determinado animal.

Comment: A questão das relações que usei para as tabelas você consideraria coerente?

Comment: Eu criaria a tabela endereços e depois a de cidades. Na tabela de atendente colocaria mais dados sobre o mesmo. Fora isso à principio está tudo ok. Mas como falei, o contexto das regras de negócio/necessidades influencia muito na modelagem de uma base de dados.

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado!